# Duvida JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, localstorage

A estrutura abaixo é um guia de como as informações são dispostas. Implemente em javascript a função `listAllDoctors()` que é responsável por armazenar a estrutura abaixo contendo os respectivos nomes e especialidades. Considere que os nomes e especialidades serão listados na DOM, conforme exemplo que segue, devendo a listagem permanecer mesmo diante do fechamento e reabertura do browser.

```
var doctors = [
'rem',
'clack',
'bruce',
'jack'
];
```

---

```
var especialidades = [
'nefrologia',
'cardiologia',
'ortopedia',
'otorrino'
];
```

**Exemplo da Saída:**

Profissionais - Especialidades

- Dr.rem-nefrologia
- Dr.clack-cardiologia
- Dr.bruce-ortopedia
- Dr.jack-otorrino

Comment: Isso parece ser um enunciado de exercício. Você ao menos tentou resolvê-lo? Poderia [edit] e adicionar sua tentativa descrevendo a dificuldade encontrada?

Answer (score 1):

Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Para saber um pouco mais, dê uma olhada no [código de conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Você traduziu isto ou o texto é assim mesmo? Parece faltar informações. O enunciado não está muito claro. Acredito que a função que faz o que se pede no enunciado seria algo assim:

```
var doctors = [ 'rem', 'clack', 'bruce', 'jack' ];
var especialidades = [ 'nefrologia', 'cardiologia', 'ortopedia', 'otorrino' ];

localStorage.setItem('doctors', JSON.stringify(doctors));
localStorage.setItem('especialidades', JSON.stringify(especialidades));

function listAllDoctors(){
     let doctors = localStorage.getItem('doctors') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('doctors')) : [];
     let especialidades = localStorage.getItem('especialidades') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('especialidades')) : [];

     for (let i = 0; i < doctors.length; i++){
         let doctor = doctors[i];
         let espec = especialidades[i];

         document.write("Dr." + doctor + "-" + espec);
     }
}

listAllDoctors();
```

Você pode ver o exemplo funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/adrianprado/3sxf1bc4/

---

Digo que o enunciado não está claro por algumas questões:

1. O enunciado diz que a função `listAllDoctors` vai armazenar, mas não imprimir no DOM.
2. Os arrays com os elementos vão ser enviados por parâmetros para a função, ou vão ser fixos neste exemplo? Se forem fixos, descarta-se o uso de Local Storage para isso.
3. Dessa forma como no exemplo que mostrei, os resultados serão sempre os mesmos, mas o texto não diz claramente o que eu fiz.

Em resumo, a função seria isso, ou alguma variação disso, mas já é um bom ponto de partida.

---

**Referências:**

[How to user Local Storage with JavaScript](https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/)